# How to publish an image on a facebook page with spring-social-facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

I am able to post a text on a Facebook Page via spring-social-facebook with PagePostData

```
PagePostData pagePostData = new PagePostData(configuration.getFacebookPageId());
pagePostData.message("Hello Spring World");
facebook.pageOperations().post(pagePostData);
```

but I cannot find how to post an image with this text. 
I think it is quite strange that these main feature would be that poorly documented.

Is there a way to do it using this framework ?